# How to test a REST service expecting a multiselect checkbox with SoapUI?

Tags: java, rest, soapui, resteasy

I'm building a REST service with Resteasy and cannot find instructions on how to submit an application/x-www-form-urlencoded multiselect checkbox list using SoapUI.  Please advise.  Thanks in advance.

Below is the method declaration.

The form will submit a list of checkboxes with the same name of "prefDressStyles."

```
@POST
    @Path( "/register" )
    @Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED )
    @Produces( "application/json" )
    public Response register( MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams )
    {
      .
      .
      .
    }
```

Comment: There is a wonderful tool called Google, tried it yet ?  :-)

Comment: I'm trying to submit using SoapUI.  Submitting test in SoapUI is my problem.  Please Advise.

Comment: @RohitGupta thanks for the sarcastic remark.  I wouldn't be here if I found it on Google.

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that in your post.  As it is, it is  offtopic but I have not downvoted it.

Comment: The question is fine.  I use SOAP UI daily and I don't know the answer offhand.

Comment: You need to tell us a little about the server side service.  What is the REST service expecting?  Without this, we cannot give you a definitive answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated the initial question.  Is that detailed enough?  I apologize if it isn't yet.  This is my very first StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the media type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, all the elements of the form will get aggregated in a POST query string looking something like the following:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2&...paramN=valueN
```

In your Java code, this string will be treated as a set of key and value pairs which will populate a `MultivaluedMap<String, String>`.

Returning to the question at hand, for the purposes of testing this REST service with SOAP UI, you should pass in a query string similar to the one above.  If you are unsure about what to pass, you can run your weh application in debug mode and have a look at the input map passed to your `register()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The POST query string should look like http://domain/serviceContext/servicePath?param1=value1&param1=value2&param1=value3...&param1=valueN

where param1 is the name of the HTML multiselect checkbox input element.

Thanks Tim Biegeleisen.  Your comment led me to the answer!  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: in SoapUI the query string will be entered in the box with the selected "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" option.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive this values on multiselect in a @FormParam("Name or Id of Your check") List valuesSelected. Hop that helps. It will give you a list of values selected in your checkbox.